# inner product for Python

Tags: python, numpy

```
x = np.random.normal(0,4,size=(n,1))
print dot(x,x)
```

Why the result returns an error about matrix dimensions,

But if I use inner it returns not inner product but like outer

```
print inner(x,x)
```

Why, what on earth inner, and dot for 1-D array?

Comment: Show the complete error message and describe what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x` is not a 1D array.  It is a 2D Nx1 array.  If you want a 1D array, you need `size=n` in your call to `normal`.

Given that, as stated in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for `np.dot`:

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication

You can't matrix-multiply an Nx1 with another Nx1.

Likewise in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html) for `np.inner`:

> More generally, if ndim(a) = r > 0 and ndim(b) = s > 0:
>
> `np.inner(a, b) = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=(-1,-1))`
>
> or explicitly:
>
> `np.inner(a, b)[i0,...,ir-1,j0,...,js-1]`
>
> `= sum(a[i0,...,ir-1,:]*b[j0,...,js-1,:])`

Comment: I find the problem, the size should be N rather than N-1 in order to do that